# How can I find an old paper I wrote that was published?

Tags: publications

When I was in college, a paper that I wrote was published. Unfortunately, I no longer have any information as to where it was published. This was in 1996–1998 time frame and was about [Title IX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_IX). Is it too old to be found? Any suggestions? I would love to show my son since he will be starting college next year.

Comment: do you have any information about the paper? For example (at least with some degree of accuracy), who were the authors, title, keywords, author affiliations? Why do you believe it was published? Was there some sort of peer review?

Comment: Talk to an academic librarian at any local college.

Comment: What name would you have used on the paper assuming it was published? I tried some combinations of the name on your profile and nothing came up that is related to Title IX. It's possible that it was published without being digitized as many journals were still print only at the time in which case you may have a lot of difficulty. Your next best bet would be to contact someone at your alma mater and ask if they can help you track it down.

Comment: By "published" do you mean in an academic journal? In a school newspaper? Something else?

Answer (score 4):

There are two critical issues that are raised by your question. First, was the article published in one of the many thousands of journals or magazines that are indexed by an indexing service?

Second, do you have any more information at all about the publication, for example,

1. Would it have been published under the full name that you used on your question or would your own name have been listed differently (e.g., R. Alcorn Smith; R. A. Smith; Rebecca A. Jones).
2. What college were you at (I'm not suggesting that you provide that information here), would you have submitted it to an internal, institutional, publication, or to a publication from outside the college.

If your article was in an indexed journal (or even *might* have been in an indexed journal) then it is highly likely that a competent librarian would be able to find it. It's worth mentioning here, that if you think that your paper was published in a specifically legal journal, then it is worth talking to a librarian who has particular expertise in law librarianship. Otherwise, you probably want a librarian who has access to databases like EBSCO.